# How can I change images with onclick and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I know how to change 1 image to another, but I want to know how to change multiple of the same image all to the same image using onclick, but individually. Like multiple copies of "Image1" should all change to "Image2" when I click on them, but one at a time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions here. HINT: Show code

Answer (score 0):

Give them all the same class, then loop through the elements.

```js
function to60() {

  var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('i40');

  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i) {
    imgs[i].src = "http://placehold.it/60";
  }

}
```

```html
<div>

  <img src="http://placehold.it/40" class="i40" onclick="to60()" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="i50" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/40" class="i40" onclick="to60()" />

</div>
```